# How to add Graylog logging in Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, graylog

I want to integrate Graylog logging in my Flutter application to centralize and analyze log data. What are the steps to add Graylog logging in a Flutter application? Can someone provide a code example or point me to some resources to help me get started? Thank you!

Comment: Assuming that Graylog is a third-party service for logging events, I'd suggest you to find the documentation page and see if they have Flutter integration. If not then you might want to contact CS or wait for someone who has used it to reply... :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any documentation so it seems like there is no support for Flutter.

As per my experience whatever data is provided in Greylog, that also provided in Mixpanel & Segment tools.

I think you should explore that two tools, it will definitely help you to solve your problem.